# Add indentation to blank lines in ActionScript code (FDT)

Tags: eclipse, actionscript-3, code-formatting, fdt

The same as this one: [Add indentation to blank lines in Java code (Eclipse IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956134/add-indentation-to-blank-lines-in-java-code-eclipse-ide) but for FDT.

Using FDT is it possible (via formatter or other setting) to automatically pre-indent blank lines in AS3 code with the appropriate number of tabs (or whitespace)?